# What is difference with observer.throw and observer.error in Observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

What is difference with `observer.throw(err)` and `observer.error(err)` ?

I'm using RxJS version "5.0.0-beta.12"

```
var innerObservable = new Observable(observer => {
    console.log('Inner observable call failed');
    observer.error(new Error('Call failed!'));
})


var outerObservable = new Observable(observer => {
    innerObservable.subscribe(
        data => {
            observer.next(data);
            observer.onCompleted();
        },
        err => {
            //observer.throw(err); // `console.error` doesn't get called
            observer.error(err);  //// `console.error` it's called
        }
    )
});

outerObservable.subscribe(
    next => {
        console.log('ok!');
    }
    , err => {
        console.error('error');
    }
    , () => {
        console.log('done');
    }
);
```

Comment: what version of `RxJS` are you using?

Comment: @shusson  "5.0.0-beta.12"

Comment: how is `innerObservable` defined?

Comment: @shusson added in question

Comment: @MohsenSarkar In fact your `observer` is an instance of [`Subscriber` class](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts). It has `error()` method but there's no `throw()` method. Where did you see `observer.throw(err)`? There's `Observable.throw()` but that's something different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact your observer is an instance of [`Subscriber class`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts). It has `error()` method but there's no `throw()` method.
There's `Observable.throw()` but that's something different.

- `observer.throw(err)` doesn't exist.
- `Observable.throw(err)` is an observable that emits just a single `error` notification.
- `observer.error()` is typically used inside `Observable.create()` callback to send an `error` notification (just like `.next()` or `.complete`) to the newly subscribed observer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `throw` method on a Subscriber.

You should see the following error if you try to call the `throw` method:

```
TypeError: observer.throw is not a function
```

Are you sure you are not catching the error somewhere?

When you [construct](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-constructor-constructor) an `Observable` the function you pass will receive a [Subscriber](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html) which implements the [Observer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html) interface.